What is the entity_type of groups in the Easy Project API?
I'm creating webhooks in Easy Project and I tried to create it for a group, but I need to find the entity type of the groups, I tried Groups, Groups, group, groups and several and nothing, it just returns the message
"{
    "errors": [
        "Action is not included in the list"
    ]
}"


the answer should be user groups
src: https://www.easyproject.com/services/api

https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/easysoftware/EasyProject/

I tried UserGroups, user_groups and derivatives and without success either...

although, they seem to use a funky path parameter pattern..   <entity>.{format}
so something like ..  groups.json

ah i see, they are using the {format} in the uri path parameter rather than using the accept header.  another candidate for apis you might hate!

I sent a message to their support, I wish I had found something today, I tried several names and without success, if you get something, let me know!

At the moment, I think the only available types that can be specified in "entity_type" during the creation of a web hook are "Project", "Issue" and "User". I haven't managed to find any other compatible entities. I was thinking about contacting Easy support. If you have any updates on this subject feel free to contact me.
